# sorting specific elements in list using Comparator

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

In Java, **using comparator**, is it possible to sort elements at the specific positions in a list? If so, how? 
Example : the list `{1,2,3,4,10,6,7,8}` 
indices of elements to be sorted `{3,4,7}`
in descending order, the result would be `{1,2,3,10,8,6,7,4}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you know the specific positions beforehand? If so, create a new list comprised of the elements you want to sort, sort the list, and then replace the elements in the original list with your sorted list, one element at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work? You would construct the Comparator with a list of the values and the list of indexes to sort:

```
private static class MyComparator implements Comparator<Integer>{

        private ArrayList<Integer> indexes;
        private ArrayList<Integer> vals;
        public MyComparator(ArrayList<Integer> indexes, ArrayList<Integer> vals){
            this.indexes = indexes;
            this.vals = vals;
        }
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer arg0, Integer arg1) {

            if(indexes.contains(vals.indexOf(arg0)) && indexes.contains(vals.indexOf(arg1))){
                return Integer.compare(arg1, arg0); 
            }
            return 0;
        }

    }
```

Comment: This was what I tried, unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: I got output that seemed like what you expected. I guess I should have tried your specific example because I do see that it is different. Sorry!